# Webpack bundler - how to inject many sources

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've got a question. How does one inject the JS code from three different files using webpack?

I've managed to write a code like just below (`webpack.config.js`), but somehow it doesn't work. In the `bundle.js` it implements only first source (`index.js`) but other two are omitted.

Can anyone help me? I'm just a noobie in this and I'm still learning. Thanks a lot.

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
     mode: 'development',
      entry: ['./index.js','./chat.js', './ui.js'],

      output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true
}
```

Comment: entry is a hashmap/dictionary that associates one or more names to sources.  I assume you are getting an implicit `"index" : [index.js, chat.js] behavior.`  Point is, you need multiple names to have multiple bundles.  Which you may or may not want - an SPA mostly only requires 1, which, in your case, would point to the 3 sources you included.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I prefer to have just one entry point that loading all dependencies, e.g. in `index.js` import other modules:

```js
import('chat.js')
import('ui.js')
```